# a generic monadic `(<|>)`?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm looking for a more concise / idiomatic way of writing `getAorB`:

```
getAorB = do
  a <- getA
  case a of
    Just _  -> return a
    Nothing -> getB
```

Does this already exist as a library function somewhere?

Note that `liftM2 (<|>) getA getB` is the same as:

```
do a <- getA
   b <- getB
   return $ a <|> b
```

which is different from `getAorB` since bind is always called on `getB` even if `getA` returns a `Just`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`maybe` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe) (`b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`) with its default value:

```
getAorB :: Monad m => m a
getAorB = getA >>= maybe getB return
```

I don't think there's a single function that does this anywhere.

Trying to use an [Alternative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) (such as [MaybeT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html)) doesn't work well here imo as it considers the second action to be fallible as well, which your `getB` isn't. If it if was, you should consider using `MaybeT` though:

```
getAorB :: Monad m => m (Maybe a)
getAorB = runMaybeT $ MaybeT getA <|> MaybeT getB
```

Comment: It should be `getAorB = getA >>= maybe getB (return . Just)`.

Comment: @AaditMShah: No, `getB` doesn't return a `Maybe`

Comment: Anther possibility:  `join $ fmap (maybe getB (return . Just)) getA`

Comment: @user5402: Uh, `join . fmap` == `>>=`?

Comment: @Bergi: `:t \getA getB -> do {a <- getA; case a of {Just _ -> return a; Nothing -> getB}}` returns `m (Maybe t) -> m (Maybe t) -> m (Maybe t)`. So, yes, `getB` does return a `Maybe`.

Comment: @MigMit: Oops, you're right. I somehow read that as `Just a  -> return a`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an `mplus` for `MaybeT`.

Answer (score 0):

Since (<|>) gets it's powers from applicative isn't this impossible?
It feels like the type you are looking for is something like

```
Monad m => a ->[m (Maybe a)] -> m a
```

instead? Or maybe

```
Monad m => a -> (a -> Bool) -> [m a] -> m a
```

Hoogle doesn't give me anything for either.

Answer (score 0):

To hide all the transformers:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

getAOrB :: m (Maybe a) -> m (Maybe a) -> m (Maybe a)
getAOrB getA getB = runMaybeT (MaybeT getA <|> MaybeT getB)
```

But I would probably just use `MaybeT` everywhere instead:

```
getAOrB' :: MaybeT m a -> MaybeT m a -> MaybeT m a
getAOrB' = (<|>)
```

Note that this type is slightly different than the type of your first implementation; it has the same type as your second implementation but better behavior.